# dynamically created controls and postback

Tags: c#, controls, postback

I have created dynamic controls (Radiobuttonlists) in an asp.net page (c#).
I create them after a button click like this.

```
RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
c2.Controls.Add(rbl);
//Set properties of rbl 
rbl.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Flow;
rbl.ID = string.Format("rbl{0}", item.QuestionID);
rbl.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
rbl.Items.Add(new ListItem("True", "1"));
rbl.Items.Add(new ListItem("False", "0"));
rbl.Items.Add(new ListItem("?", "-1"));
```

Now the problem arises when I click the submit button, the controls are lost. I know it's better to actually put the controls in page_init event. but is there no workaround so I can still initiate my controls after button click?

And is it good to first create button, then add it to control collection and then set its properties?

Thankd in advance
Kind regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

You could always put the controls into an asp:Panel on the page and then hide them until you need them, and then on postback persist a boolean and change it's visibility